# Is it possible to add a new listener, backend address pool, and request routing rule(s) to an existing Azure Application Gateway using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, azure-application-gateway

My use-case is multiple AppService apps with different lifecycles sitting behind a single Application Gateway. I'd like to add a new listener, new multi-site routing rules, and a new backend pool whenever I add a new app without tearing down and re-creating the gateway.

Initially, my plan was to have a Terraform config for shared infra that creates a skeleton Application Gateway and then have separate application-specific Terraform configs to add listeners, backend address pools, and routing rules to this gateway for each app. It seems to be impossible to accomplish with TF though.

I can clearly add listeners, routing rules and backend pools to an exiting gateway using Azure CLI or Portal. Is there a way to do it with Terraform?

Comment: Did you ever get the answer to this question?

Comment: I also need to do this with terraform. But couldn't find the answer yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to provision backend address pool separately from application gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188315/is-it-possible-to-provision-backend-address-pool-separately-from-application-gat)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is [not currently possible](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/6703) due to the fact that the Application Gateway must be initialised with at least one of each of these configuration blocks.

While it is possible to add further definitions using the Azure CLI, that behaviour isn't currently compatible with the way Terraform works. Consider what would happen if backend address pools were initially defined inline as part of the `azurerm_application_gateway` block and then further definitions of `azurerm_application_gateway_backend_address_pool` (hypothetical resource block) were also specified.

It would be nice if Terraform could deal with this situation with a union of those two definitions but unfortunately it doesn't play nicely with both inline and standalone resource blocks. Hence [the warning](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/subnet) on `azurerm_subnet` resources explaining that inline subnets on `azurerm_virtual_network` would conflict.

> NOTE on Virtual Networks and Subnet's:
> Terraform currently provides both a standalone Subnet resource, and allows for Subnets to be defined in-line within the Virtual Network resource. At this time you cannot use a Virtual Network with in-line Subnets in conjunction with any Subnet resources. Doing so will cause a conflict of Subnet configurations and will overwrite Subnet's.

Logically it wouldn't be possible to have a similar warning for Application Gateway since it's inline resource blocks are mandatory (not so for Azure Virtual Networks)

For now, the options here would seem to be

1. Manage all application-specific aspects of the Application Gateway in the same place with native Terraform.
2. Create the skeleton definition of the Application Gateway and run `local-exec` provisioner CLI commands for application-specific configuration

```
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = <<EOT
    az network application-gateway address-pool create `
      --resource-group MyResourceGroup `
      --gateway-name MyAppGateway `
      --name MyAddressPool `
      --servers 10.0.0.4 10.0.0.5 `

    EOT
    interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-command"]
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is the [reference doc](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/application_gateway.html) from Terraform for managing Azure Application Gateway.
You can refer this sample code for adding new listeners,routing rules as well as backend pools to the existing application gateway. This template carries all the required arguments like,

[http_listener](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/application_gateway.html#http_listener) - (Required) One or more http_listener blocks.

```
http_listener {
    name                           = "https-listener-1"
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = "feip"    
    frontend_port_name             = "http-port"
    protocol                       = "Http"
}
```

[request_routing_rule](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/application_gateway.html#request_routing_rule) - (Required) One or more request_routing_rule blocks.

```
  request_routing_rule {
    name                       = "${local.request_routing_rule_name}"
    rule_type                  = "Basic"
    http_listener_name         = "${local.listener_name}"
    backend_address_pool_name  = "${local.backend_address_pool_name}"
    backend_http_settings_name = "${local.http_setting_name}"
  }
}
```

[backend_address_pool](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/application_gateway.html#backend_address_pool) - (Required) One or more backend_address_pool blocks as defined below.

```
  backend_address_pool {
    name = "${local.backend_address_pool_name}"
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question about adding these components to an **existing** gateway **without** tearing down and rebuilding it. Suppose you have a gateway. Now in a different Terraform config, I want to add a new listener. I don't want to know anything about this gateway other than its name/id/resource group. And I don't want to change anything about this gateway other than adding this new listener to it. So having to fully describe the gateway in this separate config just to add a listener is not really an option I am looking for